# Output from subprocess not saved

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

When I use stdout in my Popen with stdin my process does not run.

```
def program():
    p = subprocess.Popen(link, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out = p.communicate(longquery)
    print out
```

When I run this my out comes out as (None, None) although I do have an output that shows up on the console. Why is this happening and how can I save the output that is coming out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe the output data per [the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

*"to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE too."*

```
def program():
    p = subprocess.Popen(link, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.communicate(longquery)
    print out
```

Comment: Hi thanks but for some reason when I put stdout the program doesn't seem to run at all.

Comment: @user3651858: *"doesn't seem to run at all."* is not informative. What is `p.returncode` after the `p.communicate()` call? What is `out` value? What happens if you replace `link` with `"echo abc"`? You should probably ask a different question for that if `stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT` redirects merged output in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `stdout=PIPE` as well.

Change your code to:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


def program():
    p = Popen(link, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
    out = p.communicate(longquery)
    print out
```